# Windows Task Scheduler: Task stopping due to timeout reached error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-task-scheduler

I've scheduled a task to run every 30 mins in task Scheduler in Windows Server 2008. And in the task settings,the option "stop the task if it runs longer than" is set to '1 day'. I have noticed that sometimes the task is being terminated after it has run for 10 minutes. Even the subsequent runs are also being terminated with the same error.

"Task stopping due to timeout reached"

Manually ending and restarting the task seems to solve the issue.
What can be the cause for this kind of behavior?

For a different task, the option "stop the task if it runs longer than" is set to '4 hours' and the task runs for more than 8 hours with out being terminated.

Does this option "stop the task if it runs longer than" have some other dependency that I'm missing? Why doesn't it work properly?

Answer (score 8):

For me, the problem was that this can be set in two places.  I was looking at the "stop the task if it runs longer than" setting on the Settings tab of the task properties.  There is also the same setting in the details of each item in the Triggers tab.

I had disabled the stop in the Settings tab, but not in the Triggers tab, so it was terminating it.  Once I disabled it in both places, it worked as expected.